# Wow... here, I feel I give a great/complete answer, but.. the OP does not react

Tags: discussion

Discussion, pure discussion !

Does someone knows why (sometimes, but often) the answers you feel to be the best (and the more time consuming, and often the more accurate) "statically" are the worst received ?

Human matter, surely... or... the less a subject is specialized (and so the more simple it is), the more it is useful ?

Open discussion (if this matters to someone)... not about the rep points in the points sens, but much more about how you feel BSE answers to be perceived by readers from this point of view.

Comment: If this relates in part to [my question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61849/script-for-placing-mesh-on-sphere-with-provided-latitude-and-longitude), I do really like your answer, but I'm also very busy and have not had time to properly read over it and accept it. I will at some point, do not fear!

Comment: @ShadyPuck, no no... this was more general, no worries

Comment: @ShadyPuck, by the way, I won't be connected to BSE for the next several days. So about your question, if you comment and have no answer, don't be surprised.

Comment: I feel this way a lot too, but I have learned that usually in the long run those posts will generally accrue more votes.  Many of my longest, most detailed posts got very little votes and comments at first, but now are some of my top answers.  Looking back, I noticed that six out of [my top ten answers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5705/pgmath?tab=answers&sort=votes) are ones I remember didn't get many votes at first.

Comment: What does OP stand for?

Comment: OP stands for Original Poster. I know, acronyms are frustrating. I use this site to help me find the meanings... http://www.acronymfinder.com/Slang/OP.html

Comment: @AnsonSavage [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/310919)

Comment: Do you mean "statistically?"

Comment: @cat Original Poster

Comment: @AnsonSavage I'm aware, I just thought you might find that interesting reading.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Think of the OP as your immediate target, then the rest of the blender users in the world.

At first the reaction will be from the OP, over time more people will see it, and you very likely will get more positive comments.

Now because the OP is the first target, the OP is the one that dictates the response you get - good bad, or none.
Keep in mind what kind of question you are answering, is it a simple thing where the OP glances at your answer, presses the button you told him to and then never comes back? Or a much more detailed step by step answer where the OP may have further questions?

In a few cases, new users, simple answers, or migrated questions, I don't expect to hear back.

I can definitely relate to your feelings, after writing a *long* answer just to have it be silently ignored, feels almost like a waste of time.
**But it is not.**
Even if the OP never sees it, hundreds or thousands of other people will see it and probably learn something from your answer.

Try not to get discouraged (even from a 0 UVed good answer), there are just some times where you will never hear back from the OP - no comments or any accept vote.

That just makes the positive comments you [do get](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31397872#31397872) all the more special.

---

To all users reading the site, *whenever* you find a post that helped you, UV it.
It is like giving the OP a hand shake and saying "thanks." It's just a small thing but it helps keep this site going.

Comment: Wish I could +1 again for the last paragraph

Comment: Thanks David. But there is another aspect. An example here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55355/how-to-model-a-square-starting-with-one-vertex/55359#55359. Very UVed for a so simple thing (that's part of my question too), compared to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60562/ellipse-construction-advice/60624#60624. But well, let's say, that's life... I understand your though, thanks for the answer (don't wast more time !!)

Comment: @lemon in the two examples in your comment, that is normal. :) A few reasons. The first was a hot network question, it also is a simple thing, every "new" user will get something from that. However the long detailed answer has a very limited scope. (how many people are looking to programmatically make an ellipse?) That is the big difference. No offense, but I did not even read your ellipse answer, it is just not something I care about now. That is where the big vote discrepancy comes from.

Answer (score 2):

People who react negatively to well thought out, well explained, unbiased responses to their questions are not people who are asking questions to learn... They are asking questions to hear what they want to hear. These people are not worth it IMO... If you are asking a question, you better be enough of a critical thinker to accept the responses you receive (as long as those responses are also supportive and well explain/genuinely helpful).

I am new on here and very new to blender but not new to how forums work... These people are everywhere, "Fix my problem right now and your response better be exactly what I want to hear and be super easy to do or else I'm going to scream at you." They are the ones that get a new hobby and throw a hissy-fit because they find out they aren't good at it and are not willing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This topic seems to be strongly related to [Why does no one vote](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/why-does-no-one-vote) and I believe that most of my explanation from there will also apply to this one.

One of the major problems with this is SE's possibility to post anonymously. Anonymous users (aka userXXXXX) don't log in, so they won't receive notifications when there is new activity in and around their question. I almost feel like these people are using SE as some kind of chat. Post your question, sit and wait for s.o. to answer it, rinse and repeat.

Actually I really wonder how many anonymous posters already asked more than 10 questions without feeling the need to create an account.

Comment: Related yes, but, the question is also about the ratio between the effort/complexity of the answer compared to the attention this answer receives. Like saying : much more people feel concern by simple answers

Comment: @lemon - yes, Blender is getting quite a lot of attention among Beginners lately. Not long ago those people would have chosen 3dsmax or whatever to approach 3D modeling, because it seams "easier" to understand and also more versatile. Those people might not have the slightest idea of what we are talking about thus favoring the simple answers that solve their problems. That doesn't mean we should quit giving complex in-depth answers.