# Questions related to rigging

Tags: discussion

Most Questions related to rigging are too personal and mostly falls into private session like helps. how do we approach these?

Comment: There is no obligation to answer if that's what you mean. In general I think that as long as the question is not a dupe, is on topic, is clear enough to be answered (or can be edited to made clear enough to answer), and can be of use to future users then it's no issue. If you don't feel like spending time on these, by all means, feel free to pass them up. We all volunteer our time when answering, editing, etc. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was wondering if we should down vote such questions that are basically do my job for me questions or just ignore them cause line between them are quit blurry for me.
But I guess just ignoring them seems fair.

Comment: Well, re: voting, I feel should vote regardless up or down on most everything. The help explains in more detail, here are some helpful pages to read through on that...https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up  also,https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down also [this meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/why-does-no-one-vote) Do you have a specific example of a Q in mind that would help users understand your meaning also?

Comment: You can and should always cast whatever vote you feel is adequate for a post. If you feel it is too localized you can and should also flag it for being too localized. The community will then arbitrate on your vote and decide. If enough people agree with you it will then get closed otherwise it might remain open, no harm done.

Comment: "Do my job for me questions" are intended to be closed.  There is a specific reason for that in the close vote dialog (IIRC, as a sub-dialog of "community specific reason.")  It doesn't matter if they're looking for paid work or volunteer work, both are reasons for closing a question.  Of course, there's a very fuzzy line between looking to understand and looking to get somebody to do it for you; it is very easy for two users to disagree on where to draw the line.